# Could I order in EJBQL by a function which is not mapped to a column in database?

Tags: java, jpa, ejbql

I would like to order a query by a function which uses properties of the class. Something like:

```
@entity
class A
{
private int id;
private String name;

public int StringLength()
{
return name.length();
}

}
```

And the sentence something like: `select n from A order by name.StringLength()`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, but if you want to query based on the length of one of the property you can use the length function similar to SQL:

```
select n from A order by length(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

David's answer was right - you cannot call the function - but in EJBQL the query should look something like this:

```
select n from A n order by length(n.name)
```